# Could not extract ResultSet when mapped into hbm.xml file

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a union query

```
SELECT al.C_PERSIST_ID AS id, tkl.C_PERSIST_VERSION AS version, tkl.C_TENANT_ID AS tenantId, tkl.C_MESSAGE AS message, tkl.C_CREATED AS created, tkl.C_INT_STATUS AS statusDB, tkl.C_INT_PRIORITY AS priorityDB,tkl.C_ASSIGNED_PERSON_ID AS assignedPersonId, tkl.C_SOURCE AS name, tkl.C_MAJOR_VERSION AS majorVersion, tkl.C_MINOR_VERSION AS minorVersion, tkl.C_ARCHIVED_FLAG AS archived, tkl.C_DEFINITION_ID AS definitionId,al.C_ALERT_DATETIME AS alertDateTime, al.C_ESCALATION_LEVEL AS escalationLevel, al.C_MAX_ESCALATION_LEVEL AS maxEscalationLevel, al.C_WORKFLOW_TO_START AS workflowToStart al.C_ESCALATED_FLAG AS escalatedDB,al.C_DUEDATE AS dueDate
            FROM tkl_Alerts al INNER JOIN tkl_TaskList_Items tkl ON al.C_PERSIST_ID = tkl.C_PERSIST_ID
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT distinct du.C_TASKLISTITEM_ID 
            FROM tkl_Distribution_Users du 
            WHERE du.C_USER_ID = 'karishma.shaik@infor.com' AND du.C_IS_PERSON = 1) X ON tkl.C_PERSIST_ID = X.C_TASKLISTITEM_ID
            WHERE tkl.C_ARCHIVED_FLAG = 0 
                AND tkl.C_INT_STATUS <> 40 
                AND tkl.C_INT_STATUS <> 50 
                AND tkl.C_ASSIGNED_PERSON_ID IS NULL 
                AND X.C_TASKLISTITEM_ID IS NOT NULL
            union

SELECT al.C_PERSIST_ID AS id, tkl.C_PERSIST_VERSION AS version, tkl.C_TENANT_ID AS tenantId, tkl.C_MESSAGE AS message, tkl.C_CREATED AS created, tkl.C_INT_STATUS AS statusDB, tkl.C_INT_PRIORITY AS priorityDB,tkl.C_ASSIGNED_PERSON_ID AS assignedPersonId, tkl.C_SOURCE AS name, tkl.C_MAJOR_VERSION AS majorVersion, tkl.C_MINOR_VERSION AS minorVersion, tkl.C_ARCHIVED_FLAG AS archived, tkl.C_DEFINITION_ID AS definitionId,al.C_ALERT_DATETIME AS alertDateTime, al.C_ESCALATION_LEVEL AS escalationLevel, al.C_MAX_ESCALATION_LEVEL AS maxEscalationLevel, al.C_WORKFLOW_TO_START AS workflowToStart, al.C_ESCALATED_FLAG AS escalatedDB,al.C_DUEDATE AS dueDate
            FROM tkl_Alerts al INNER JOIN tkl_TaskList_Items tkl ON al.C_PERSIST_ID = tkl.C_PERSIST_ID
            WHERE tkl.C_ARCHIVED_FLAG = 0 AND tkl.C_INT_STATUS <> 40 AND tkl.C_INT_STATUS <> 50 AND tkl.C_ASSIGNED_PERSON_ID = 'karishma.shaik@infor.com'
            ORDER BY tkl_Alerts.C_ESCALATION_LEVEL DESC, tkl_Alerts.C_PERSIST_ID DESC
```

When I map that into hbm.xml file its giving errors like:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:277)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.dao.TaskListItemHeaderDao.lambda$executeItemQuery$45(TaskListItemHeaderDao.java:661)
    at com.infor.ion.persist.multitenant.hibernate.Transactional.doInTransaction(Transactional.java:73)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.dao.TaskListItemHeaderDao.executeItemQuery(TaskListItemHeaderDao.java:655)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.dao.TaskListItemHeaderDao.getMyAlertHeaders(TaskListItemHeaderDao.java:443)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.dao.TaskListItemHeaderDao.getMyAlertHeaders(TaskListItemHeaderDao.java:455)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.logic.TaskListItemHeaderManager$DaoRetry$3.doInRetry(TaskListItemHeaderManager.java:276)
    at com.infor.ion.process.common.persist.WithRetry.doInRetry(WithRetry.java:77)
    at com.infor.ion.process.common.persist.WithRetry.doInRetry(WithRetry.java:113)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.logic.TaskListItemHeaderManager$DaoRetry.getMyAlertHeaders(TaskListItemHeaderManager.java:272)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.logic.TaskListItemHeaderManager.getMyAlertHeaders(TaskListItemHeaderManager.java:78)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.logic.PulseUIServiceImpl.getMyAlertHeaders(PulseUIServiceImpl.java:149)
    at com.infor.ion.process.pulseengine.pulseui.api.services.PulseApiUIProxyService.getMyAlertHeaders(PulseApiUIProxyService.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please format your question - that is impossible to read.

Comment: The answer could very well be further down in the stack trace, any other exceptions mentioned right below the part of the stack trace you have posted? Some line starting with Caused by: ...

Comment: aused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)

Comment: Do you even need a UNION for this, looks like one select should do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't support UNION. What you can do is create a view and create a Entity class based on that or use native query for this case.

Comment: query is giving results in sql server